# What is the use of combining a 'bind' as a callback to an invocation of 'on'?

Tags: jquery

What is the use of this line of code: `list.on('dblclick', 'label', this.edit.bind(this));`

I am confused as to why `this.edit.bind(this)` is being passed instead of just `this.edit`. Note, this is from the ['todo mvc' jquery example](http://todomvc.com/architecture-examples/jquery/#/all), and the first version of this was indeed written without the bind call. It was added in a later update. Context:

```
var App = {
    init: function () {
        this.todos = util.store('todos-jquery');
        this.cacheElements();
        this.bindEvents();

        Router({
            '/:filter': function (filter) {
                this.filter = filter;
                this.render();
            }.bind(this)
        }).init('/all');
    },

    },
    bindEvents: function () {
        var list = this.$todoList;
        list.on('dblclick', 'label', this.edit.bind(this));
        list.on('click', '.destroy', this.destroy.bind(this));
    },

    edit: function (e) {
        var $input = $(e.target).closest('li').addClass('editing').find('.edit');
        $input.val($input.val()).focus();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is used in this case because the author wants `this` inside the `edit` method to refer to the `App` object.

By default `this` inside a event handler will refer to the current target of the event, so if you want to call a method of `App` inside the event handler you won't be able to use `this.methodname(....)`.

In such cases we can use [$.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy)/[Function.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to pass a custom execution context to the callback function.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up! I mistook the bind() for a jQuery bind.